# How to set round corners for a custom Dialog?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment, material-components-android

This is code for my custom Dialog:

```
public class DialogBrightness extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, null);
    
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    /*Build and create the dialog here*/
    
    }
}
```

I followed instructions from other answers by first creating this drawable xml called dialog_bg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid
            android:color="#fff5ee"/>
        <corners
            android:radius="30dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```

Then setting it as the background of the layout_dialog xml:

```
android:background="@drawable/dialog_bg"
```

But I can't do the final step which is to set the dialog's root view to transparent:

```
dialogBrightness.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

because there's no getWindow() function.

Also when they say root view do they mean the one that I set to null in the inflate function above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` included in the Material Components library:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;

public class CustomDialog extends DialogFragment {

    //...

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        return  new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(getActivity(),R.style.MaterialAlertDialog_rounded)
                .setTitle("Title")
                .setMessage("Message")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                .create();

    }
}
```

with:

```
<style name="MaterialAlertDialog_rounded" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Dialog.Rounded</item>
</style>

<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Dialog.Rounded" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">8dp</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this one is a little more simple.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend @GabrieleMariotti's answer but I am writing here to see how you could have implemented in your original way.

> there's no getWindow() function.

You could have used `requireView()` instead as :

```
dialogBrightness.requireView().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

> Also when they say root view do they mean the one that I set to null in the inflate function above?

Yes, it is. Generally, it is not recommended to pass `null` as a `root` parameter as `root` view is needed to calculate the layout parameters of the `view` that is currently being inflated by the `LayoutInflater`. Instead, you should use it like this :

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(requireContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, rootView, false);
```

Here, 3rd parameter is `attachToRoot` which is passed as `false`.

Comment: What is rootView exactly?

Comment: `rootView` is an object of type `ViewGroup`(it extends `View` class and is a base class for layouts and view containers). If attachToRoot is false, `rootView` is **only** used to calculate layoutparams otherwise the currently inflated `view` would be **child** of the `rootView`.