# Android Custom Dialog Corner Radius

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-dialogfragment

I am inflating a custom dialog in my android app. The layout of the dialog is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    app:cardElevation="3dp">
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/interior_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"/>
        
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

This is my code to inflate the dialog:

```
        Dialog alertDialog  = new Dialog(activity);
        alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.layout_progress_dialog, null);
        alertDialog.setContentView(dialogView);
        Objects.requireNonNull(alertDialog.getWindow()).setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

However, the corner radius is not being set. The corners are still sharp. I tried using Alert Dialog but there I faced the problem that it covers the entire width (just like Progress Dialog). With Dialog, I can have the width as much as needed.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need a `CardView` to obtain the corner radius.

Just use the **`getTheme`** method:

```
class RoundedDialog: DialogFragment() {

    override fun getTheme() = R.style.RoundedCornersDialog
    
    override fun onCreateView(...): View? {
       val v: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout...., container, false)
       return v
    }

    //...
}
```

with:

```
<style name="RoundedCornersDialog" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Dialog">
        <item name="dialogCornerRadius">16dp</item>
</style>
```

[image]

If you want to use a **`AlertDialog`** you can create it in the `onCreateDialog`. Check this [answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703501/how-to-set-round-corners-for-a-custom-dialog/62705027#62705027).

Comment: Is it possible to set the corner radius to the theme programmatically? I have to set the corner radius based on user input

Comment: This is a simple yet working solution. Even though it does not answer OP's question, It does add border radius to DialogFragment.

Comment: Just to add a detail to Gabriele answer: the style from what you are inheriting to create the RoundedCornersDialog, override the textColor and other stuff so, if you  previously have text in your dialog and after applying style, the text disappear, or some other elements are changing colors, make sure you define the attribute you want to stay unnmodified in the style. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for creating a drawable and then making it the background of the view.

You can use the following piece of code to make round corners- just create a new drawable and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
    <solid android:color="#2ED771" />
    <padding
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="15dp" />
</shape>
```

WIth this you can also specify radius of each corner independently

Comment: If I want to set the corner radius programmatically using this file, how can I do it? I have to change the corner radius based on user input.